# Get Block Number (without web3)

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping to have some client side javascript run that will do some simple timing estimates based on the current block number.  Is there a simple way to do this that doesn't require web3? I don't need access to any other data from the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

There's [JSON-RPC API](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API). In particular querying a provider [eth_blockNumber](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_blocknumber) should return the current block number.